# error: lvalue required as left operand of assignment for &d1->b = d2; but no error for d1 = (void *)d2;

Tags: c, pointers, structure

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

struct s1
{
    uint8_t a;
    uint16_t b;
    uint8_t c;
};

struct s2
{
  uint8_t d;
  uint8_t e;
};

int main()
{
    struct s1 *d1;
    struct s2 *d2;
    
    d1->a = 1;
    d1->b = 2;
    d1->c = 3;
    
    d2->d =4;
    d2->e =5;
    
    &d1->b = d2;

    return 0;
}
```

Why doesn't `&d1->b = d2;` work? `b` is 32 bit and the `struct s2` is also 32 bit? As we are just assigning the address.

If that line is changed to `d1 = (void *)d2;` It works without an error.

Comment: `&d1->b` is a temporary, `d1` is not.

Comment: What are you trying to do with `&d1->b = d2`? None of that makes any sense.

Comment: Also, you declare `d1`, `d2`, but never allocate any memory to it.

Comment: I don't have time to write an answer, but it lies in the fact that no standard conversion sequence exists for the former, but since you've performed an explicit conversion for the latter, it'll compile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First. The pointer `d1` and `d2` are not initialized. Using this pointer invokes Undefined Behavior. To fix it I suggest making the the actual object with automatic storage.

```
struct s1 d1;
struct s2 d2;
```

You cannot assign `d2` to `d1.b` because the types do not match. `struct s2` and `uint16_t` are not compatible. To do this type of type punning use `memcpy()`.

```
memcpy(&d1.b, &d2, sizeof d2);
```

Comment: That still doesn't make any sense. `sizeof d2` will be lager than `sizeof d1->b`, and the call will lead to undefined behavior. Not that any of the pointers are pointing anywhere anyway.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude, yes, I haven't noticed that `d1` and `d2` were pointer, not automatic objects. Answer was updated